# What does it mean $1Z in regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm not familiar with regex, but I have the following string

```
d.$filter = d.$filter.replace(/TutoringSince le '(.+?)'/g, "TutoringSince ge $1Z");
```

Is anybody know what does it mean this Z char after $1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It replaces the captured text in the `d.$filter`, with `TutoringSince ge`, plus itself then **adds** a `Z`. I.e. the text

> TutoringSince le 'whatever'

would turn into

> TutoringSince ge whateverZ

"The captured text" would be anything inside the single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is a reference to the first group - in this case: `(.+?)`

`Z` is just a `Z` letter.

Comment: what does it mean just Z letter?

Comment: Literal, capital letter Z. i.e. it will add Z at the end of the first captured group.

Comment: @BorHunter It is a regular text like `TutoringSince...`

Comment: @MariaDeleva thank you